# jQuery plugin Drag and drop(Bootstrap)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you suggest a drag and drop plugin that can be use with bootstrap?
[image]

Instead of checking, i want it to be drag and drop from Available Approvers/Member to Selected Approvers/Members

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets) will work well.You will either need to *find* a bootstrap theme, or override the default jQuery UI styles with your own css.